# How android can parse mailto url containing Japanese or Chinese characters

Tags: android, mailto

i've tried to parse a mailto url which contains Japanese or Chinese characters by using MailTo.parse(url) but it return null.
it's ok with English characters. How do I resolve that? 
There's my code and logcat:

```
try {
                    url = URLDecoder.decode(url,"UTF-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "url:    " + url);
                MailTo mt = MailTo.parse(url);
                Log.d(TAG, "body:    " + mt.getBody());
                Log.d(TAG, "subject: " + mt.getSubject());
07-12 12:50:34.861: D/Fbaku(9484): url:    mailto:?subject=幕末の時代を生き抜け！&body=iPhoneとiPod Touch対応の風雲幕末史を一緒にやりませんか？

07-12 12:50:34.861: D/Fbaku(9484): subject: null
07-12 12:50:34.861: D/Fbaku(9484): body:    null
```

Edit: sorry, my mailto url contains a link in body like this: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17607307

So MailTo.parse(url).getBody() and MailTo.parse(url).getSubject() return NULL

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try by using **toString()** method

so **change**

```
Log.d(TAG, "body:    " + mt.getBody());
Log.d(TAG, "subject: " + mt.getSubject());
```

**to**

```
Log.d(TAG, "body:    " + mt.getBody().toString());
Log.d(TAG, "subject: " + mt.getSubject().toString());
```